# numpy sum of each array in a list of arrays of different size

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of numpy arrays, each of different length, as that obtained by doing `lst = np.array_split(arr, indices)`, how do I get the sum of every array in the list? (I know how to do it using list-comprehension but I was hoping there was a pure-numpy way to do it).

I thought that this would work:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: arr.sum(), axis=0, arr=lst)
```

But it doesn't, instead it gives me this error which I don't understand:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (12,)

*NB: It's an array of sympy objects.*

Comment: Please see if this works : [sum(x) for x in lst]

Answer (score 2):

There's a faster way which avoids `np.split`, and utilizes [`np.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html). We create an ascending array of indices where you want to sum elements with `np.append([0], np.cumsum(indices)[:-1])`. For proper indexing we need to put a zero in front (and discard the last element, if it covers the full range of the original array.. otherwise just delete the `[:-1]` indexing). Then we use the `np.add` ufunc with `np.reduceat`:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(1, 11)
indices = np.array([2, 4, 4])

# this should split like this
# [1  2 | 3  4  5  6 | 7  8  9  10]

np.add.reduceat(arr, np.append([0], np.cumsum(indices)[:-1]))
# array([ 3, 18, 34])
```

Comment: Awesome thx! that's a very handy feature I didn't know about. One remark though: the indices for array_split are not the chunk-lengths but the splitting indices, so you don't need the `np.cumsum(arr)[:-1]` part. And also coincidentally my indices come from doing `_, indices = np.unique(arr, return_index=True)` on a different array, so the `0` at the front is already present.